# My code stops running at the cin statement (VSCode Code Runner EXT)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Whenever I try to use this extension to automatically run code for me, it stops at the std::cin statement and doesn't let me input anything. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int num;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cout << num*5;
}
```

This code runs up until the std::cin statement and doesn't let me input anything in the console or terminal.

Comment: `std::cin` causes the program to stop (it blocks waiting for input). So type the input and hit `[Enter]`. Why are you using some extension to run your code. Compile it and hit `ctrl + j` to open the terminal in VS code and then run it there.

Comment: Did not know about `ctrl+j`. I always use `ctrl+\``.

Comment: perhaps you were just looking at the output panel? Did you check the terminal panel if the input prompt was happening there?